# Facebook Share Dialog with Blob Data

Tags: facebook, fbsdksharedialog

Is there any way I can pass blob directly to facebook share dialog since I dont have any url. I have an image in the form of blob data which I want to post on facebook.

window.FB.ui({
display: 'popup',
method: 'share',
action_type: 'og.likes',
action_properties: {
object : my blob data
}
}, function(response){});

Above code is not working since object only takes https url. Is there any way I can pass blob data

Comment: No, there is not. You can only share HTTP(S) URL via the Share dialog.

Comment: is there anyway we can convert blob data to https temporary url and later delete it?

Comment: Sure - if you send it to a server first. Then that server can provide a URL for Facebook to fetch the image from.

Comment: I am sending it to server now using fetch() post method. How do I get the url back after uploading ?

Comment: By making your server include it in the data you send back ...?